# Simplify A Trig Expression

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{\tan (A) + 1}{\sec (A)}$$

i have tried to simplify using the pythagorian identies and cannot figure out the correct answer

Comment: Try first separating it into two fractions...

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\tan(A)+1}{\sec(A)}
&=(\tan(A)+1)\cos(A)\\
&=\sin(A)+\cos(A)\\[4pt]
&=\sqrt2\sin(A+\pi/4)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\tan A}{\sec A} + \frac{1}{\sec A}$$

$$\tan A = \frac{\sin A}{\cos A}, \cos A = \frac{1}{\sec A}, \sec A = \frac{1}{\cos A}$$
Using the following trigonometric identities the above becomes:

$$\frac{\sin A}{\cos A} \cdot \frac{\cos A}{1} + \cos A = \sin A + \cos A$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\tan(A)+1}{\sec(A)}=\frac{\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}+1}{\frac{1}{\cos A}}=\frac{\frac{\sin A+\cos A}{\cos A}}{\frac{1}{\cos A}}=\sin A+\cos A$$